# How can i convert a VirtualBox's .vdi files to VMWare vmdk/ovf formt

Tags: vmware-converter, vdi, conversion, ovf

Vsphere takes ovf file to create a Virtual Machine, but it also needs the vmdk which is the actual disk.
Would VMWare Converter be able to do this conversion? i have the .vdi files on Mac OSX. Maybe i need to move the files to where VMWare converter can access them, since there is no VMWare converter on Mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use QEMU (Available for OS X) to do the conversion with the following command:

qemu-img convert VirtualBox-HardDisk-image.vdi -O vmdk VMware-virtual-machine-image.vmdk

Comment: could you please give me the url to download QEMU for Mac OSX, if you have it handy. i went to the QEMU site, and it seems i need to compile it from Source

Comment: http://qemu.darwinports.com/

Comment: thanks so much, also one more question, when i have the converted VMDK, it seems i would also need teh .ovf file , is there a way to generate it?